# UITabBarController with 4 tabs each tab enabled with UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to do a project with 4 tabs using UITabBarController which has scrolling for each tab in which I want to Insert different objects and write code.

In a empty application, I initially created 4 XIB's for 4 tabs and I'm successful in creating 4 tabbed view with the following code.

```
//ExTabBarAppdelegate.m


#import "ExTabBarAppDelegate.h"
#import "PersonalViewController.h"
#import "EmpViewController.h"
#import "FinancialViewController.h"
#import "TermsViewController.h"

@implementation ExTabBarAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    PersonalViewController *perVC=[[PersonalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PersonalViewController" bundle:nil];

    EmpViewController *empVC=[[EmpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EmpViewController" bundle:nil];

     FinancialViewController *finVC=[[FinancialViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FinancialViewController" bundle:nil];

     TermsViewController *terVC=[[TermsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TermsViewController" bundle:nil];

     [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:perVC, empVC, finVC, terVC, nil]];

    self.window.rootViewController=tabBarController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But how should I enable scrolling property for each tab ??
Please help !
Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

In your XIB files, use `UIScrollView` instead of `UIView` for your viewController's view.

Here is a tutorial about UIScrollView :

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/